# ReIndex after updating the Product name via API's in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, reindex, indexing

Am re-indexing the Product programmatically every time its name is updated via API. But still, it shows old data. The code which I use to reindex a product,

```
$indexers = array('catalog_product_category');
$indexer = $this->indexerFactory->create();
foreach($indexers as $indexerId){
    $indexer->load($indexerId)
     ->reindexRow($productid);
}
```

Also, In Backend, I configured "Update on Save" in Index Management.
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: It could be that you are running a foreach on a string.  try changing the first line to `$indexers = array('catalog_product_category');`  Also, the catalog_product_category indexer is for category-assignments, you probably need the `catalog_product_attribute` indexer.  Last, with the "Update on Save" option, none of that should be necessary for the name.  Have you cleared both the Magento cache and your browser's cache?

Comment: @mtr.web: Thank you for your Quick reply.I made a mistake in the post, Am sending $indexers as an array. Unfortunately, I Could not recommend clearing cache to my customers.While reindexing it takes time to complete, so my product is not coming in frontend for sometime when doing this

Comment: Looks like this works:

`$indexers = [Loading all indexers here];
$indexer = $this->indexerFactory->create();
foreach($indexers as $indexerId){
    $indexer->load($indexerId)
     ->reindexRow($productid);
}`